# Trying to load an offsite page in Fancybox lightbox on form submit

Tags: forms, fancybox, lightbox, form-submit

I'm attempting to load a lightbox (via Fancybox) on submission of a mailing list sign-up form. The sign-up form action loads an off-site link to Constant Contact when a form is submitted. Normally, this page is loaded in a standard pop-up, which does work just fine.

But, because folks often have pop-ups blocked, we're trying to spiff it up with a lightbox.

So here's the rub: when I submit the form, it loads the lightbox, but won't load the page in the lightbox. I suspect this is because it's not passing the information through to the iframe/lightbox and it's likely because I don't have it set up properly. I'm hoping someone can help, as I'm not totally that versed in jquery yet. I may not even need to use iframe, I'm not sure.

I did find this reference to [passing the information via ajax](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), but I'm not totally clear on how that works. I also [found this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648312/fancybox-form-submit), but it's not really clear how they resolved it.

Here is my code, perhaps you can help? :) I'd appreciate it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#iframe").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
        'transitionOut' :   'fade',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true,
    });


});
```

Here is the form:

```
<form name="ccoptin" id="signup" action="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="llr" value="yyyyyy">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="xxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="oi">
<label>sign up for new services and promotions:</label>
<input type="text"name="ea" value="" class="text" /> <input type="submit" id="iframe" class="submit" name="go" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I appreciate your input and please bear with me, as I am a relative jquery/ajax newb.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the form being loaded within the lightbox?